# PHPUnit output text is messed up

Tags: php, unit-testing, text, phpunit

I don't know if I should be asking this here since this is not entirely programming-related but please pardon me in advance.

How do I correct the highlighted text in the screenshot below?

The "<-[" texts.

Also, how do I run PHPUnit in Windows that will show show the usual green/red bar when passing/failing tests? I tried Git Bash console but it also displays messed up output and no bar.

[image: messed up display text]

Comment: **PLEASE** use google before you ask http://superuser.com/questions/208150/phpunit-windows-command-box-nice-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at ANSI colour codes, which don't work in `cmd.exe`.

The [configuration file](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) can be used to set the `colors` directive to `false`. Alternatively, you should be able to use the [`--colors` command line option](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions).